# 3 x 2 or 6 x 2 Surface Reconstruction

Tags: material-science, structure-formation

I encountered expressions such as "3 x 2 surface reconstruction" or "6 x 2 surface reconstruction" while studying.

I understand surface reconstruction refers to the movement of atoms on the surface such that the atomic structure on the surface is different from that of the rest of the crystal.

But what does the preceding numbers such as "3x2" or "6x2" mean?

Answer (score 0):

An $m \times n$ surface reconstruction means that a new unit cell, reconstructed on the surface of a crystal, takes up as much surface area as $m \times n$ pristine unit cells. For an example I have researched, [this link](https://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/semitech_en/kap_3/advanced/t3_3_1.html) at Christian-Albrechts-Universität zu Kiel shows a $7\times 7$ reconstruction of the Si(111) surface.

[image: Surface reconstruction of silicon, taken from https://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/semitech_en/kap_3/illustr/si-7x7.jpg]

Whereas atoms on a pristine surface were arranged in a periodic structure, atoms on the reconstructed surface are now arranged in a new structure with a 7-fold larger spatial period, in groups of $7\times 7$.

Comment: And the reconstruction is not limited to integer numbers.